# "newsletter" needs to be changed to "digest" in the side bar too

Tags: feature-request, newsletter, sidebar

Recently Newsletters were renamed to Digests all over the Stack Exchange sites.

But in the side bar for example, digest is still referring to newsletter. The button text is renamed to "Sign up for the digest", but there are two places it still is "newsletter".

Can these be renamed to "weekly digest!" and "example digest"?

> [image: digests]

Comment: What?? Hard to digest such a weird change.